# Select element of different parents that are in same position

Tags: xml, xpath

Say I have the following XML snippet

```
<line>
  <data>
    <p>5<p/>
    <p>40<p/>
    <p>30<p/>
    <p>25<p/>
  </data>
  <attData>
     <att>
     </att>
     <att>
       <type>
         <n/>
         <value>no use</value>    
       </type>
     </att>
     <att>
       <type>
         <n/>
         <value>use</value>    
       </type>
     </att>
     <att>
       <type>
         <n/>
         <value>no use</value>    
       </type>
     </att>
  </attData>
</line>
```

There are many *line* elements in the xml document that have child elements of the same name and sequence such that for each *line* element the number of descendant *p* elements always equals the number of descendant *att* elements. So there is consistent pattern repetition.
Is there a way to match a *p* element to an *att* element by its corresponding document order from its parent?
I am trying to work out a xpath expression to select only *p* elements which don't have a corresponding *value* equal to *'no use'*
So the above xml would output:

```
     5  
     30
```

I am trying to avoid using a variable for position() as I need the expression to be used for a sort select.
I have:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="*/line/attData/att[not(type[value='no use'])]">
```

which selects the required *att* elements
and from which:

```
  <xsl:value-of select= "count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
```

provides the document order of the *att* from *attData*, but I can't figure out how to match this order and select the required *p* elements.
Any help will be very much appreciated, I am fairly new to this.
I am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: That is terrible XML design.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a key

```
<xsl:key name="pos" match="line/data/p" use="concat(generate-id(../..), '|', count(preceding-sibling::p))"/>
```

then in your code you could use

```
<xsl:template match="line/attData/att[not(type[value='no use'])]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pos', concat(generate-id(../..), '|', count(preceding-sibling::att)))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to process the corresponding `att` elements. Or for sorting maybe

```
<xsl:for-each select="*/line/attData/att[not(type[value='no use'])]">
  <xsl:sort select="key('pos', concat(generate-id(../..), '|', count(preceding-sibling::att)))" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```